# Caching and Loading local Images asynchronously in tableview

Tags: ios, multithreading, uitableview, asynchronous

Hi i am pretty new to IOS so pardon for silly questions . I am working on an app which loads large images in a tableview. Images to be loaded are of large size (>5MB) so i am trying to resize the image into thumbnails ,cache it and the load it asynchronously to table view.  i found many ways and discussions for doing the same for network images (SDWebImages etc.) but i couldn't get anything for doing the same with local images (camera/photo library). Can any one tell me how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement lazy loading of image along with asynchronous loading of images.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2010/05/downloading-images-for-table-without.html

Comment: But all these examples are for loading network images. I want to load local images (Camera/photo Library)